# Dimension of curvature invariants

Tags: rt.representation-theory, riemannian-geometry, invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

**EDIT:** Let $V$ be a Euclidean space and let $O(V)$ denotes its orthogonal group.
Let $K(V)\subset Sym^2(\wedge^2(V))$ denote the subspace of curvature tensors, i.e. the subspace of elements satisfying the algebraic Bianchi identity
$R_{i[jkl]}=0$.

Let us denote by $D_k(n)$ the dimension of the subspace of $O(V)$-invariant tensors in $Sym^k(K(V))$ where $n=\dim V$. It is easy to see that $D_k(n+1)\geq D_k(n)$. Moreover
$$D_k(2k)\geq D_k(2k-1)+1.$$

**Question.Is it true that $D_k(n)=D_k(2k-1)+1$ for all $n\geq 2k$?**

I think that for $k=1,2$ the answer to this question is positive.

Remark. The motivation of this question comes from an attempt to count polynomial invariants of the Riemann curvature tensor on Riemannian manifolds. The connection is that the curvature tensor of a Riemannian manifold $M$ belongs to $K(TM)$.

Comment: Are you sure that you wouldn't rather have the dimension of the space of $\mathrm{O}(V)$ invariants of degree $k$ on the subspace $K(V)\subset \mathit{Sym}^2(\Lambda^2(V))$ of curvature tensors (which is a proper subspace of $\mathit{Sym}^2(\Lambda^2(V))$ as soon as $\dim V >3$)?

Comment: According to your motivation, you should be looking at tensor powers of the space of tensors of $(2,2)$ Young type (probably what Robert meant by $K(V)$ above), which is the actual symmetry type of the Riemann tensor, rather than $Sym^2(\wedge^2 V))$. The difference is accounted for by the algebraic Bianchi identity. I believe this "plethysm" problem is fairly complicated and may not have an easy to write down answer. I recommend looking up standard references like [Fulling, King, Wybourne, Cummins (1992)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/9/5/003).